# curl use response body as next get header

Tags: curl

Is there anyway that curl can use/store a POST response field "`session-id: <session-id-string>`" in the next Get request header as "`auth: <session-id-string>`" to the same server?

this is how the server authorize the login users.

Do I need to make a bash script to grab the session-id from POST response field and then insert it into the next GET header?

Comment: Don't use bash, use python urllib2 with a cookie jar. It'll be easier.

Comment: ok thanks. will take a look at it.